# Управление курсором в С#

Tags: c#

Может кто подскажет как управлять положением курсора
Например в Combobox введено слово 
Как программно установить курсор после 3 буквы?

Comment: Как управлять положением курсора вообще или как установить курсор в combobox? Для первого используются глобальные хуки, для второго методы самого combobox без всяких изощрений. Все зависит от конкретной задачи. Ваш вопрос сейчас слишком общий и не имеет универсального ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос, "как программно установить курсор после 3 буквы?"

`this.comboBox1.Select(0, 3);`